# Launch docker on lein test

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Can I execute a terminal command when `lein test` is invoked?

I'm trying with

```
:aliases {"docker-launch" ["run" "-m" "docker" "run" "-it" "--rm" "-p" "27017:27017" "mongo:4.2"]}
:profiles {:default {:prep-tasks ^:test ["docker-launch"] }}
```

But it only concatenates the docker string with `lein run`.  I need to launch the docker container to execute tests.

Comment: You may want to look into [contajners](https://github.com/lispyclouds/contajners) or [clj-test-containers](https://github.com/javahippie/clj-test-containers)

Comment: @SteffanWestcott Thanks, seems to be useful, will try to implement it through the day.

Comment: I would use a shell script (bash/zsh) to launch the container, and then invoke whatever you need from `lein`

Comment: @AlanThompson If you add an answer that shows how to run a shell script as a pre-task, you have basically answered that question (as it should not make any difference for what process to run)

Comment: No need for the script, thank you. In fact I already have a ci on github using it. The issue was with a pre config on jenkins that executes `lein test` without launching the docker container.  That's why I wanted to know if there's a way to do it without turning to scripts. on lein itself.

Comment: But it seems I will need to adapt the code using one of the solutions Steffan proposed.